# How to use projection interfaces with pagination in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get a page of a partial entity (NetworkSimple) using the new feature of spring data, [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts)

I've checked the documentation and if I request only:

```
Collection<NetworkSimple> findAllProjectedBy();
```

It works, but if I'm using pageable:

```
Page<NetworkSimple> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```

It throws an error:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.expression.function.AggregationFunction$COUNT cannot be cast to org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.expression.CompoundSelectionImpl
```

Any one has already work with this ?

My NetworkSimple class is the following:

```
public interface NetworkSimple {
    Long getId();

    String getNetworkName();

    Boolean getIsActive();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Note:** This feature should work in the way described by the original poster but due to [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-909) it didn't. The bug has been fixed for the Hopper SR2 release, if you're stuck on an earlier version then the workaround below will work.

It is possible to use `Pageable` with the new query projection features introduced in Spring Data JPA 1.10 (Hopper). You will need to use the `@Query` annotation and manually write a query for the fields you require, they must also be aliased using `AS` to allow Spring Data to figure out how to project the results. There is a good example in [spring-boot-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/src/main/java/sample/data/jpa/service/HotelRepository.java) part of the spring boot repository.

In your example it would be quite simple:

```
@Query("SELECT n.id AS id, n.name AS networkName, n.active AS isActive FROM Network n")
Page<NetworkSimple> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```

I have made the assumption that your entity looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Network
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private boolean active;

    ...
}
```

Spring Data will derive a count query automatically for the paging information. It is also possible to make use of joins in the query to fetch associations and then summarise them in the projection.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. This actually should work as the original poster expects but you present a valid workaround. I've changed [the ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-909) that was filed by the original poster to update the docs with your workaround to fix the actual bug. Would be cool, if you could update your answer to mention it. Fix will be in Hopper SR2.

Comment: The ticket is fixed, snapshot builds available, to be included in SR2 of Hopper.

Comment: @OliverGierke I have updated the answer. I had assumed that it was just a limitation as I couldn't find any examples of it being used this way.

Answer (score 2):

Even with spring-data-jpa 1.11.4, something like

```
public interface NetworkRepository extends JpaRepository<Network, String> {
    Page<NetworkSimple> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

would not compile; reporting

```
findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) in NetworkRepository clashes with findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) in org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
return type org.springframework.data.domain.Page<NetworkSimple> is not compatible with org.springframework.data.domain.Page<Network>
```

The workaround we found was to rename findAll to findAll**By**, e.g.

```
public interface NetworkRepository extends JpaRepository<Network, String> {
    Page<NetworkSimple> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create `findAllProjectedBy()` as specification.Then you can use `findAll()` method like this.

example :`findAll(findAllProjectedBy(),pageable)`

Following link may be help to find how to create specification in spring.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 1):

You can use  interface projection with Pageable like this :

```
Page<NetworkSimple> findPagedProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```

with some parameter :

```
Page<NetworkSimple> findPagedProjectedByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may come from the method name. The by keyword means that you ae filterig data by a specific property: findByName for example. Its called query creation from method name:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

So try with `Page<NetworkSimple> findAll(Pageable pageable);`

Comment: If I remove the "By" it returns an error message, because it couldn't create the query.

`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllProjected found for type Network!`

Comment: My bad you should use the findAll method name

Comment: But I can't use that because the return is a Network object, and I want the projection.

Comment: it seems that you can add an annotation to your repository to specify the projection: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/rest/projections/src/main/java/example/springdata/rest/projections/CustomerRepository.java

Answer (score 0):

### Implementing interface projection with pagination

**1. Our `ResourceEntity.java` class**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class ResourceEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**2. Creating projection Interface name `ProjectedResource.java`, which maps data collected by the SQL query from repository layer method**

```java
public interface ProjectedResource {
  Long getId();
  String getName();
  String getAnotherProperty();
}
```

**3. Creating Repository layer method: `getProjectedResources()`**

- We are considering the database table name is `resource`.
- We are only fetching `id` and `name` here.

```java
@Query(name="select id, name, anotherProperty from resource", countQuery="select count(*) from resource", nativeQuery=true)
Page<ProjectedResource> getProjectedResources(Pageable page);
```

Hope the issue will be resolved!

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
@Query("SELECT n FROM Network n")
Page<? extends NetworkSimple> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```